# Error: src/app/dashboard.component.ngtypecheck.ts:174:51 - error TS1003: Identifier expected. 174 "" + (((_t48 /*5654,5655*/). /*5656,5656*/) /*565

Tags: angular, typescript

i have this json file :

```
{
        "id": 1276,
        "etabName": "YAssineDev",
        "etabType": "OUR_SCHOOL",
       "users": [
            {
                "id": 12,
                "username": "YassineDev",
                "firstName": "yassine",
                "lastName": "messaoud",
                "active": true,
                "payant": false,
                "creatdateTime": "2021-06-08",
                "roles": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "roleName": "ADMIN_USER",
                        "description": "admin user"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

i want to display the username of the users tab in the html,
but it shows me this errors :

```
Error: src/app/super-admin/dashboard/dashboard.component.ngtypecheck.ts:174:51 - error TS1003: Identifier expected.

174         "" + (((_t48 /*5654,5655*/). /*5656,5656*/) /*5654,5656*/);
                                                      ~
```

i have tried with *ngFor:

```
<tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let t of tabs.users">
            <td>{{ t.username }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

**getMethod**

```
  dataEtabUser() {
    this.cr.getdataEtab().subscribe(data=> {
      this.tabs = data
    })
  }
```

**ngOnInit**

```
this.dataEtabUser()
```

**Service**

```
getdataEtab(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8020/survey/etablissement/')
}
```

but nothing displayed

Comment: Can you try to create a Minimal Reproducible Example in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)? FYI, you cannot directly access users with `tabs.users`. Based on your JSON, tabs may contain more than 1 element. It should be `tabs[0].users` if your tabs contain only 1 element / try to get first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ISSUE(S) & CONCERN(S)

Based on your attached JSON, you cannot access users as `tabs.users` as `tabs` contain at least 1 or more elements.

I expect your JSON is an array of the elements seems you have a comma at the end of the JSON.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1276,
        "etabName": "YAssineDev",
        "etabType": "OUR_SCHOOL",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 12,
                "username": "YassineDev",
                "firstName": "yassine",
                "lastName": "messaoud",
                "active": true,
                "payant": false,
                "creatdateTime": "2021-06-08",
                "roles": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "roleName": "ADMIN_USER",
                        "description": "admin user"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Hence, you need to iterate with each element in `tabs` then only able to retrieve `users`.

---

## SOLUTION(S)

### SOLUTION 1: Apply another outer layer for *ngFor to iterate with `tabs` element(s).

```
<div *ngFor="let t of tabs">
  <p>TabName: {{t.etabName}}</p>
  <p>TabType: {{t.etabType}}</p>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <td>Username</td>
      <td>Firstname</td>
      <td>Lastname</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of t.users">
        <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <hr />
</div>
```

[Sample StackBlitz for Solution 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tzypnf)

---

### SOLUTION 2: Retrieve only the first element of `tabs`

*If you are expected to retrieve the first element only from `tabs` JSON, you may refer to this solution.*

1. Rename to `tab` (type: `any`) to avoid confusion as only retrieve one element.

> .component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  tab: any;

  ...

  dataEtabUser() {
    this.cr.getdataEtab().subscribe(data => {
      if (data)
          this.tab = data[0];
    });
  }
}
```

> .component.html

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>Firstname</td>
    <td>Lastname</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of tab.users">
      <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Sample StackBlitz for Solution 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jy1rdr)